# Hive - python connection error

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

**Here is code :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyhs2
try:
with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost',
           port=10001,
           authMechanism="PLAIN",
           user='root',
           password='test',
           database='test') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        #Show databases
        print cur.getDatabases()

        #Execute query
        cur.execute("select * from raw_stats")

        #Return column info from query
        print cur.getSchema()

        #Fetch table results
        for i in cur.fetch():
            print i

except Thrift.TException, tx:
print '%s' % (tx.message)
```

**Error!**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/py/test.py", line
>   8, in  database='default') as conn:   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyhs2/**init**.py", line 7, in
>   connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyhs2/connections.py", line 46, in
>   **init**
>       transport.open()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line
>   55, in open
>       self._trans.open()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line
>   101, in open
>       message=message) thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:10001

Comment: Its resolved by starting hiveServer2 service and change the port 10000

Answer (score 0):

It resolved by starting hiveServer2 service and changing the port 10000.