# Unable to connect to Hive2 using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, hive, cloudera

While connecting to Hive2 using Python with below code:

```
import pyhs2

with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost',
           port=10000,
           authMechanism="PLAIN",
           user='root',
           password='test',
           database='default') as conn:
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    #Show databases
    print cur.getDatabases()

    #Execute query
    cur.execute("select * from table")

    #Return column info from query
    print cur.getSchema()

    #Fetch table results
    for i in cur.fetch():
        print i
```

I am getting below error:

```
File
"C:\Users\vinbhask\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pyhs2-0.6.0-py3.6.egg\pyhs2\connections.py",
line 7, in <module>
    from cloudera.thrift_sasl import TSaslClientTransport ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cloudera'
```

Have tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370431/how-to-access-hive-via-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088937/hive-python-connection-error) but issue wasn't resolved.

Here is the packages installed till now:

```
bitarray0.8.1,certifi2017.7.27.1,chardet3.0.4,cm-api16.0.0,cx-Oracle6.0.1,future0.16.0,idna2.6,impyla0.14.0,JayDeBeApi1.1.1,JPype10.6.2,ply3.10,pure-sasl0.4.0,PyHive0.4.0,pyhs20.6.0,pyodbc4.0.17,requests2.18.4,sasl0.2.1,six1.10.0,teradata15.10.0.21,thrift0.10.0,thrift-sasl0.2.1,thriftpy0.3.9,urllib31.22
```

Error while using Impyla:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\HiveConnTester4.py", line 1, in <module>
from impala.dbapi import connect
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\impala\dbapi.py", line 28, in <module>
import impala.hiveserver2 as hs2
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py", line 33, in <module>
from impala._thrift_api import (
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\impala\_thrift_api.py", line 74, in <module>
include_dirs=[thrift_dir])
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\parser\__init__.py", line 30, in load
include_dir=include_dir)
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 496, in parse
url_scheme))
thriftpy.parser.exc.ThriftParserError: ThriftPy does not support generating module with path in protocol 'c'
```

Comment: I'm amazed that so many people complain suddenly about PyHive (which is currently broken *[Aug 2017]*) and PyHS2 (which you clearly cannot make work). Try ImPyla instead. It's maintained by Cloudera. And it works.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: I had tried in Impyla as well, updated the error log for that as above

Comment: How about PySpark?

Comment: Looks like you have a rogue dependency in your Python stack that plays hell with all DB drivers... I suggest that you make a separate, clean Python install, but with Anaconda; then a clean install of Impyla (with the Anaconda installer, cf. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/impyla). If that one works, then you will know for sure that your current Python install is to blame.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: Done as advised and below is the error: File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\QA_DataValidator\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\protocol\binary.py", line 178, in read_message_begin
    message='No protocol version header')
thriftpy.protocol.exc.TProtocolException: TProtocolException(type=4)

Comment: @cricket_007: Can we connect to remote HIVE2 server from our local system using pyspark?

Comment: Back to the basics: (1) which version of Hive are you running server-side and (2) does anyone else connect successfully to that thing?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Assuming the firewall allows you to

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter 1: Hive 2.1.1-mapr-1703-r1, 2: No one else am the first person trying for some automation scripts earlier I had connected via Java JDBC APIs to the same server using Eclipse java program

Answer (score 1):

thrift_sasl.py is trying cStringIO which is no longer available in Python 3.0. Try with python 2 ?

Comment: We have a requirement to use python3+

Comment: pysh2 is no longer maintained. Do you try with PyHive ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install an unreleased version of thrift_sasl. Try:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/cloudera/thrift_sasl
```

Comment: @Vinod was this helpful?

Comment: No am getting this error "Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out"

Comment: The last error hints you're behind a firewall - that's why you're getting a timeout on accessing port 443. Change `https:` to `http:` and try again - port 80 might be open.

Comment: Getting this error after changing to http "fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/cloudera/thrift_sasl/': Failed to connect to github.com port 80: Timed out
Command "git clone -q http://github.com/cloudera/thrift_sasl C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-5_9y1ynj-build" failed with error code 128 in None"

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable learning PySpark, then you just need to setup the `hive.metastore.uris` property to point at the Hive Metastore address, and you're ready to go.

The easiest way to do that would be to export the `hive-site.xml` from the your cluster, then pass `--files hive-site.xml` during `spark-submit`.

(I haven't tried running standalone Pyspark, so YMMV)